# Hago click en 'Submit' y el item se incluye en el array, pero no aparece en pantalla (React JS)

Tags: array, reactjs

Estoy realizando una ToDo app, la cual lleva incluido el feature `Drag and Drop`.
La cuestión es que la aplicación en sí funciona bien, y cada vez que en la barra de `input` introduzco una tarea y le doy `Submit`, puedo ver en la Consola que se está añadiendo al `Array` correspondiente (el de `Todo`)

Sin embargo, aunque se añade al array, no llego a verlo en pantalla y no sé bien cómo solucionarlo.

Os dejo una captura de cómo lo veo, y debajo el código de la App (y el código del componente que lleva incluido):

[image: Vista de la consola y la aplicación]

Código de la aplicación:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

import nextId from 'react-id-generator';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from '@hello-pangea/dnd';
import _ from 'lodash';

import TodosList from '../todo/todos-list';


export default function Todos() {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        "todo": {
            title: "Todo",
            items: []
          },
          "in-progress": {
            title: "In Progress",
            items: []
          },
          "done": {
            title: "Completed",
            items: []
          }
        })

    function handleChange(e) {
        const value = e.target.value;

        setTitle(value)
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        setState(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                todo: {
                    title: "Todo",
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: nextId(),
                            title: title
                        },
                        ...prev.todo.items
                    ]
                }
            }
        })

        setTitle("");
    }

    function handleUpdate(id, value){
        const temp = [...todos];
        const item = temp.find((item) => item.id === id);
        item.title = value;
        setTodos(temp);
    }

    function handleDelete(id){
        const temp = todos.filter(item => item.id !== id );

        setTodos(temp);
    }

    function handleOnDragEnd() {
        (result) => {
            const { source, destination } = result;
            if (!destination) {
              return;
            }
            if (
              source.index === destination.index &&
              source.droppableId === destination.droppableId
            ) {
              return;
            }

            const itemCopy = {...state[source.droppableId].items[source.index]}

            setState(prev => {
            prev = {...prev}

            prev[source.droppableId].items.splice(source.index, 1)

            prev[destination.droppableId].items.splice(destination.index, 0, itemCopy)

            return prev
            });

        };
    };



    return (
        <div className='todo-container'>

            <h1>Welcome to your To-Do App</h1>

            <form className='todo-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className='todo-input'
                    value={title}
                />
                <input 
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                    type="submit"
                    value= "Add"
                    className='btn-add'
                />
            </form>

            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
                {_.map(state, (data, item) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={item.id} className="column">      
                            <h2>{data.title}</h2>
                            <Droppable droppableId='todos'>
                                {(droppableProvided) => (
                                    <div
                                    {...droppableProvided.droppableProps}
                                    ref={droppableProvided.innerRef}
                                    className='todos-list-container'>
                                        {todos.map((item, index) => (
                                            <Draggable
                                            key={item.id}
                                            draggableId={item.id}
                                            index={index}>
                                                {(draggableProvided) => (
                                                    <div
                                                    {...draggableProvided.draggableProps}
                                                    ref={draggableProvided.innerRef}
                                                    {...draggableProvided.dragHandleProps}
                                                    className='todo-item'
                                                    >
                                                        <TodosList
                                                        item={item}
                                                        onUpdate={handleUpdate}
                                                        onDelete={handleDelete}/>
                                                    </div>
                                                )}
                                            </Draggable>
                                        ))}
                                    {droppableProvided.placeholder}
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </Droppable>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </DragDropContext>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Y el código del componente `TodoList`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function TodosList({item, onUpdate, onDelete}) {

    const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false);

    function FormEdit() {
        
        const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState(item.title);
        
        function handleSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        function handleChange(e) {
            const value = e.target.value;
            setNewValue(value);
        }

        function handleClickUpdate() {
            onUpdate(item.id, newValue);
            setIsEdit(false);
        }

        return  <form className='form-edit' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" className='todo-input' onChange={handleChange} value={newValue}/>
                    <button className='btn-update' onClick={handleClickUpdate}>Update</button>
                </form>
    };

    function TodoElement() {
        return  <div className='todo-element'>
                    {item.title}

                    <button className='btn-edit' onClick={() => setIsEdit(true)}> Edit </button>
                    <button className='btn-delete' onClick={(e) => onDelete(item.id)}> Delete </button>
                </div>
    }

    return (
        <div className='todos-list'>
            {isEdit ? <FormEdit /> : <TodoElement />}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que no te aparece en pantalla? El componente drag and drop?

Comment: Te pregunto porque no llego a entender, pero el unico problema que veo esta relacionado con eso. Despues de la linea ``{todos.map((item, index) => (`` deberias envolver tu componente ``<Draggable></Draggable>`` con un ``return()``

Comment: Hola @AgustinG. ! 
Lo que no me aparece en pantalla es que cuando introduzco en la barra alguna tarea y le doy a ``Add``, pues no aparece dentro de la lista de ``Todos``, que es donde debería estar. Sin embargo en la consola sí que puedo ver que se ha introducido, pero no se imprime en pantalla.
Y respecto a la solución que me has comentado (la de envolver el componente ``Draggable`` con un ``return()``) no me funciona, de hecho me da error :(

Comment: Si podes subir tu codigo tal cual funciona a algun sandbox o algo por el estilo, compartime el link. Gracias

Comment: Hola @AgustinG. !! Finalmente sí que funcionó, lo volví a hacer de nuevo y efectivamente me faltaba un ``return()`` por ahí envolviendo el componente ``Draggable``, y con eso y cambiando la key, funcionó, así que gracias!!

Comment: Listo, me alegro que se haya solucionado. Lo agregué como respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta envolver el componente `<Draggable>` que devuelve el map `todos.map((item, index) => (`

con un `return()`

Ya que no estas retornando el resultado de la funcion `map`

```
{todos.map((item, index) => (
return( // agrego esto
 <Draggable
   key={item.id}
   draggableId={item.id}
   index={index}>
    {(draggableProvided) => (
      <div                                               
        {...draggableProvided.draggableProps}
        ref={draggableProvided.innerRef}                  
        {...draggableProvided.dragHandleProps}
        className='todo-item'
      >
        <TodosList
          item={item}
          onUpdate={handleUpdate}
          onDelete={handleDelete}/>
        </div>
    )}
  </Draggable>
 ) // y agrego esto
))}
```